# implementing data grid using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, csv, editor

I need to read data from a CSV file & display it as a data grid. The CSV file contains name-value pair i.e. column `A` will contain `name` & column `B` will contain its `value`. Also, the user can add a blank row to the end of it & insert data manually by clicking on an add button. The user can select any row & delete the row completely by pressing on the delete button.

What would be a good approach towards implementing this, especially deleting selected rows?

Comment: i think the question is pretty clear in my problem statement.I need to read a csv file..display it in a grid..with functionalities of removing the added rows.Basically like an excel sheet

Comment: You want us to write code for you?

Comment: no...the approach would be enough..especially deleting the selected records.please note that the user should be able to delete any record not just the first or the last

Comment: @JJ: Did you know you can accept an answer for any of the questions you've asked?  You'll earn 2 rep points for each one you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite at the moment is jQuery dataTables:

http://www.datatables.net/

if you want to parse CSV data I would look at FileHelpers:

http://www.filehelpers.com/

its free

Answer (score 1):

The **JQGrid plugin** does pretty much everything you want.  Several demos are here:

http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

You can download it from here:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6

In addition, there is a **jQuery CSV plugin** here:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/csv